# Android, How do you launch the Default Music Player

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to start the default music player on a ICS/Jellybean device. Looking at the API17 on android devloper I can;t manage to figure out how to simply build an intent to will launch the default music player rather than prompt the user to select a music player. I find the later overly intrusive on a user if they have a default already set. Why should you prompt them for input every single time? I don't understand that part of the >4 logic.

On my >4 devices I have multiple players. I want to simple launch the default player but I can not seem to get the intent correct. I continue to get the popup to select an application. Do I need to use component in the intent? Any help please?

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=15){
    Intent intent=Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,
    Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);
    startActivity(intent);
}else{
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");//Min SDK 8 and deprecated in API 17 for makeMainSelectoryActivity
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the package name to start the particular application

The below won't work on all devices as package name may be different for the default music player. **Not a good idea and i would not recommend the below since your app won't be targeting a particular phone**.

```
  Intent i = new Intent();
  PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
  i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sec.android.app.music");
  // in my case  the package name is com.sec.android.app.music
  i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
  startActivity(i);
```

Also should you not let the user chooser the app to be launched. Different users may like to use different media player installed on the phone. **I would suggest you leave it to the user to launch media player of their choice.**

Comment: This is a horrible idea.  First off, sec is Samsung Entertainment Corporation.  This will only work on Samsung phones, and not even all of them (they don't all use the same player, every Samsung model has a different set of software).

Comment: @GabeSechan agreed. yes i mentioned that in my case the package name is "com.sec.android.app.music". I also suggested to leave the choice of using the media player to the users.

Comment: I would be happen if the "Complete Using Action" would retain the previous selection if you select always. It does not seem to do this even within the same application. It just continues to pop up irrespective of selecting "Just Once" or "Always".

Answer (score 0):

The prompts that launch to make them choose a player has a "use always" and a "use once" button.  If they want to always use the same player, they'll hit use always the first time and the intrusion is gone.  Until they've done that they don't have a default music player.

If your problem is just launching the music player at all-  launch an intent to view the mp3 MIME type.  Then the user can pick their app from the subset of apps that play MP3s, hit use always, and the picker will never show again.

Comment: if you have google play music the package name is `"com.google.android.music"`. can this be used in all cases considering the app is installed on phones.

Comment: No it can't.  It won't exist on old phones, as it may not have been ported back that far.  It may not have been installed by default, as OEMs don't install all of Google's software.  And like the rest of Google Play and Google Play Services, if the OEM didn't pay Google the OEM can't install it.  It also may not work on custom ROMs, as I doubt they could install it if they wanted to.  ANd finally it could have been uninstalled by the user.  Never assume an app with a given name is installed, unless you control the hardware.

Comment: agreed. so the best option is to leave it to the user to choose the media player of his choice.

Comment: Actually the use always and use once does not appear to work for some reason. The prompt always returns no matter what you select as your choice. There are numerous others that have posted messages to the same effect. I'll make a separate stand alone button and see if makeMainSelectorActivity actually selects and remembers the always part but it simply has not worked so far with the code above that i pasted......always prompts....always....so very annoying

Comment: Redone a very simple project. In fact I used the source code for Android your first app. I placed the code above in the SendMessage for when the user pushes the button of Send. Every time you press the button android prompt with "Complete Action Using" irrespectively of picking once or always. It never rembers the previous selection if you use "Always". Surely there has to be a mechanism where this actually works as intended and ALWAYS means always and it stores and uses it next time? This doesn't seem to be the case and its a very simple intent.

Comment: it appears that you can only set default applications for mime types but you can not set default applications for categories. Setting a mime type of mp3 and then invoking the intent definitely works. However, trying to do this on a application based on a category definitely does not do anything at all. You continually get the popup. Rather strange. I would say that the <15 API set had it all over the API17 in being able to call the default MUSIC_PLAYER.